# Mad Max-style book ID circa late 80s early 90s: sex zombies and dildo machine gun

Tags: story-identification, novel, post-apocalyptic

I'm trying to identify a paperback book from memory that I bought in the Petersfield, UK, branch of John Menzies some time around 1990. The details I have are as follows:

**Date:** pre 1993 - The earliest I could have bought this book would be 1989. My suspicion is that I lost this book pre-Aug 1990, but I may be wrong and there is a possibility that I bought it later, although no later than 1993.

**Theme:** The book had a pretty generic, derivative post-apocalyptic Mad Max-style setting and, I believe, cover. The story itself (as I remember it) was written in a relentlessly violent, pulp style, inc extreme and particularly unpleasant sexual violence. The following are two key features of the narrative that I remember:

- A virus called something like 'Project X' that was man-made and that turned people into undead or mindless zombies but with an insatiable sexual appetite.
- A Thunderdome style gladiatorial combat between two women gladiators. One of these wore a strap-on dildo that enclosed a machine gun. Her final victory being to kill her opponent through penetrating them and firing this device.

I have no memory of the author's name other than it was male and most likely British in origin.

I'd be immensely grateful for any suggestions. It's for a research project, which if it goes ahead I'd make sure to acknowledge anyone who helps track this down.

Comment: Not the answer, but had to shout out to Flesh Gordon

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis ha! Actually that's a good point to clarify, the book wasn't an exercise in camp, more grim hypermasculinity. From memory (which could be wrong) I think it took itself pretty seriously.

Comment: It's hard to picture as serious from your description, but I'll take your word on it.  I guess it's not Get Smart: The Nude Bomb either.

Comment: This got a plus 1 simply for *sex zombies and a dildo machine gun*. I am now home brewing something along those lines in our D&D campaign.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A possibility: This could be part of David Alexander's over-the-top, gore-and-sex filled *[Phoenix](https://www.goodreads.com/series/96565-phoenix)* series. I would suggest book 2, *[Ground Zero](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1863545.Ground_Zero)*. IIRC, it takes place in post-apoc Vegas and has all manner of Thunderdome-like games as well as a drug called "SPASM-X" that causes people to become mindless sex zombies.

[image: Front cover of Ground Zero]

From [this review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/3226876547?book_show_action=true):

> I'm just guessing, but I think David Alexander watched "Mad Max Beyond Thunderdome" while writing this.in the book we have Vegas, Max had Bartertown. There is a midget/dwarf who plays a big part in helping Phoenix. Sort of like The Master in the movie. Instead of Thunderdome, we have the murder marathon, a car race to the death. We do have our hero blackout in the desert, like Max, but instead of children rescuing him, we get a bunch of loonies called Earthbound. A cult that lives in a missile silo underground. They have all sorts of fun with sex, drugs, and mutant creatures. That's about where the similarities end. Although that's pretty much the 3/4th of this book.
>
> The ending has Phoenix in a showdown in a ghost town with six killers of the new order. Since there is a book three, you can guess that it has an open ending. This is pretty much all go, no slow action. The killing is only stopped by the hard core sex.

Comment: That sounds very much like it! Thanks guys. Very interesting that it's part of a series, as I don't remember that key factor it seems fitting. I will chase it down and confirm. Thanks again.

Comment: From the other review on Goodreads: "There's sordid sex with ex porn stars, action galore, more bizarre named characters, gun porn and a cliffhanger ending which sees our hero carted off by Tallon." "Gun porn" may refer to your machine gun dildo.